# How to fix my encoding Issues between Unity and Java Spring Server?

Tags: spring, unity-game-engine, encoding, utf-8, unitywebrequest

I am sending a UnityWebRequest to my Java Spring Server from my application in Unity. If I send the word "house", then "houseÔÇï" arrives there. However, the error does not happen when I send the request from Postman, for example.

The creation of the Request in Unity:

```
    private UnityWebRequest CreateRegistrationRequest()
    {
        var webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(REGISTRATION_URL, string.Empty);

        webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        webRequest.SetRequestHeader("charset", "utf-8");

        var req = new RegistrationRequest();

        req.email = usernameField.text.Trim();
        req.password = passwordField.text.Trim();

        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(req);
        webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
        return webRequest;
    }
```

My application.yml:

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
spring:
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/registration?charSet=UTF8
    username:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        connection:
          charSet: UTF-8
    show-sql: true
```

RegistrationRequest:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class RegistrationRequest
{
    public string email;
    public string password;
}
```

As mentioned, the error does not appear when I send the request from Postman.

I assume that the issue has something to do with the Byte Order Mark (BOM), which seems to be optional in UFT-8 and is not supported by every platform. Therefore I tried to disable the BOM:

```
        webRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(jsonData));
```

It did not work. Same issue. I even tried to change the encoding to utf-32, but same issue as well.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `RegistrationRequest`? Have you tried printing out the `jsonData` and verified it has the right format?

Comment: Hi, I added the implementation of RegistrationRequest to the question. And I just tried to print the jsonData out, it seems to be correct.

Comment: Of what type are `usernameField` and `passwordField`? Are those by chance `TMP_Text` components of a `TMP_InputField` ?

Comment: They are both TextMeshProUGUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing now that actually the two `usernameField` and `passworsField` are `TextMeshProUGUI`:

This is quite a known "issue"!

The `TextMeshProUGUI` component of a `TMP_InputField` should **NOT** be used to retrieve the text value!

Indeed it might even be completely unusable since e.g. for a password type field the text component itself literally only contains `"*******"`. It is also known (as in your case) to contain some hidden control characters only meaningful to the `TMP_InputField` component itself.

See e.g. [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmesh-pro-ugui-hidden-characters.505493)

⇒ What you want to do instead is make both fields of type `TMP_InputField` instead.

This one also has a property called `text` which will contain the actual value without hidden control characters!